# Validate 2 depth array on Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-7

Is there a way to validate this `array()`, Nothing works so far:

```
[
  {
    "transaction": {
      "user_id": 6,
      "month": 12,
      "year": 2084
    },
    "entities": [
      {
        "name": "Allan Botsford",
        "value": 3,
        "is_total": false,
        "type": "CASH"
      },
      {
        "name": "Luisa Schiller Sr.",
        "value": 6266,
        "is_total": false,
        "type": "CASH"
      },
      {
        "name": "Susie Deckow MD",
        "value": 506700,
        "is_total": false,
        "type": "CASH"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "transaction": {
      "user_id": 7,
      "month": 5,
      "year": 2002
    },
    "entities": [
      {
        "name": "Raquel Jast",
        "value": 7,
        "is_total": false,
        "type": "CASH"
      },
      {
        "name": "Wendell Herman I",
        "value": 4480,
        "is_total": false,
        "type": "CASH"
      },
      {
        "name": "Oceane Greenfelder DDS",
        "value": 46344,
        "is_total": false,
        "type": "CASH"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I can validate the transaction with the following rules:

```
[
        '*.transaction.month' => 'required|numeric',
        '*.transaction.year' => 'required|numeric',
        '*.transaction.transaction_date' => 'sometimes|date_format:Y-m-d'
]
```

The problem is in the nested `entities` array because the following rules are ignored:

```
return [
        '*.entities.*.is_total' => 'required|boolean',
        '*.entities.*.name' => 'required|string',
        '*.entities.*.value' => 'required|numeric',
        '*.entities.*.type' => ['required', Rule::in(CashTemporaryInvestment::TYPES)]
]
```

I don't find any hint on laravel documentation. I will appreciate any help. I am using Laravel 7

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Validator wildcard will work using the following `preg_match()` as seen in the `Validator` class

```
$pattern = str_replace('\*', '([^\.]+)', preg_quote($this->getPrimaryAttribute($attribute), '/'));
```

So your pattern will work if you can access the attributes using
`[0]['entities'][0]['is_total']` for your rule `'*.entities.*.is_total' => 'required|boolean',`

Comment: Ok, but the entities validations are ignored. Only the transaction rules are evaluated